# Java regular expression to split the String

Tags: java, regex, string

How would I split a string upon one or more spaces in between, preserving the effect of having more than one space.

e.g. when the input string is:

```
s = "a bc de fg "; 
spl = s.split(" ");
```

gives me the array

```
{a, bc, de, fg}.
```

how do I get the same array to 1-or-more spaces in between, like

```
s = "a  bc  de     fg ";
```

TIA.

Comment: just split the string using the regex ` +`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `+` [quantifier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html) meaning "one or more".

```
String s = "a  bc  de     fg ";
String[] parts = s.split(" +");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts)); // [a, bc, de, fg]
```

You may also consider using `\s` which matches any white space character.

```
String[] parts = s.split("\\s+");
```

Comment: The ``*`` quantifier means "zero or more"

Answer (score 2):

Just split the string using the below regex,

```
String tok[] = s.split(" +");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tok));
```

`<space>+` matches one or more spaces.